# Sending Array to AJAX and Accessing Passed Data to Controller in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm trying to get the table data and store it in an array and pass it in the controller so i can write in PHP excel. I've tried using other data and it worked. Now when I try to use this my excel file is empty.

Here is my Javascript code

```
    var TableData = new Array();
    $('#tblmonthlydues tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row] = {
            "amortid" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            , "duedate" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            , "customername" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "lotdesc" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
            , "daysdue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text()
            , "amountdue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text()
            , "amortdue" : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
            , "surcharge" : $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').text()
            , "vat" : $(tr).find('td:eq(8)').text()
            , "ips" : $(tr).find('td:eq(9)').text()
            , "interest" : $(tr).find('td:eq(10)').text()
            , "principal" : $(tr).find('td:eq(11)').text()
            , "payments" : $(tr).find('td:eq(12)').text()
        }
    });
    TableData.shift();
    var data = JSON.stringify(TableData);
    data = data.substring(0, data.length - 1).substring(1, data.length);
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  baseurl + "collection/get_monthly_dues_report",
        data: {'data':data},
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href = baseurl + "collection/get_monthly_dues_report";
        },
        error: function(data){

        },
    });
```

Here is My Controller

```
$data = $this->input->post('data');
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data as $r) {
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array(
    $r['duedate'], $r['customername'], $r['lotdesc'], $r['daysdue'],
    $r['amountdue'], $r['amortdue'], $r['surcharge'], $r['vat'], $r['ips'],
    $r['interest'], $r['principal'], $r['payments']), null, 'A' . $row
  );
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()
              ->getStyle('A' . $row . ':L' . $row)
              ->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()
              ->getStyle('A' . $row . ':L' . $row)
              ->applyFromArray($styleArray4);
  $row ++;
}
```

Comment: Why did you set processData and contentType? Usually you only need to set both to false if you are sending something like a FormData object. And don't want jQuery to process the object or set the content type (underlying XHR would set it). Try removing those and see if that helps. Also you would need to json_decode on the php side

Comment: Tried removing cache, processData and contentType. Added $data = json_decode($data); to the controller and still nothing.

Comment: Why are you also doing the data.substring() calls? That is going to mess with the JSON possibly malforming it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans and also when i try to print_r($data) it shows nothing.

Comment: @PatrickEvans i removed it and still empty excel data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot to convert JSON data into associative array use

```
json_decode($data,true);
```